# jquery.mobile: no event triggered when loading an external page into the dom

Tags: events, jquery-mobile

Ok, first off do NOT confuse my use of the word "external" with the keyword external used in anchor tags. That's NOT what this is about.

I have a multiple page document and everything there works fine. I also have several other .html pages that are rarely ever used (i.e. about page) so I don't want to clutter the dom with them but rather load them as needed.

So, starting with the about.html page, when loaded, this page will (or should) give some info about the device it's running on as well as the version number of my app and whether or not there's a later version available (some people turn off automatic updates).

Before I go further, I want to put it on the record that the about.html page is working in another app when it's loaded with the rel="external" attribute set but I'm trying to move away from that.

So, inside my index.html I have a header with a nav bar and the anchor tag is  straight forward:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="homeMenu" data-theme="b">    
      <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" >
        <li><a href="about.html" class="ui-icon-info">About</a></li>
```

When I run the app in a simulator, the about.html gets loaded into the dom and becomes the active page so that part is working but not one event that I can figure out gets triggered.

I have tried all of the following:

```
$("body").on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function( event, ui ) {
    console.log("Going to: " +ui.toPage[0].id);
});

$(document).on('pagecreate', function() {
    $(':mobile-pagecontainer').on('pagecontainerbeforeshow', function(event, ui) {
        console.log('pagecontainerbeforeshow triggered');
        console.log("Going to: " +ui.toPage[0].id);
    });
});

// $( "#aboutPage" ).on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function( event ) {
$( "#aboutPage" ).on("navigate", function( event ) {
    console.log("aboutPage Ready!");
    initMenu();
    onAboutReady();
    $('#aboutPage').on("swiperight", function () {
        // I know, I know... one step at a time ;-)
        window.location.href = 'index.html'; 
    });  
});
```

I would imagine that I can't attach an event handler to the about page as the about page doesn't yet exist in the dom so there must be another way to attach an event that actually gets fired.

What am I missing here?

Comment: here is an event debug page: [Page Events Demo](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/page-events/)

Comment: Thanks for that... I was really excited but I can't get it to load and run in my mobile app simulator... docs.php has to be run off of a server.

Comment: don't give up, `docs.php` is downloading this resource file: `http://api.jquerymobile.com/resources/api.xml` just put it inside a  folder and add reference in the head of your page: `var docs = $.parseXML( *content of xml file* )`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer is easier than one might think! Instead of trying to trap an event for specific page that's not in the dom, simply trap the event for all pages, add in a switch statement and viola!

```
$("body").on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function( event, ui ) {
    console.log("pagecontainerbeforeshow -> Going to: " +ui.toPage[0].id);
    switch(ui.toPage[0].id)
    {
      case "aboutPage": // <div id="aboutPage" data-role="page"
            break;
    }
});
```